# scipy.optimize curve fit giving strange results when using part of a data set

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to use scipy.optimize curve_fit to fit the exponential function:

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return c - (c-a) * np.exp(-b * x)
```

I import my data from a tdms file, and on the original data everything works ok:

```
data = td[gps[0].name][chns[10].name][:]
time = td[gps[0].name][chns[10].name].time_track()

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, time, data)
resulting = func(time,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2])
plt.plot(time,data)
plt.plot(time,resulting)
plt.legend(['Actual Temp','Calculated Temp'])
```

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DUI4.png)

However, in these data sets there is often a small portion of the data that I don't want to be included at the beginning and at the end. So I tried to grab a portion of the data, but when I do that I no longer get values that make sense:

```
data = td[gps[0].name][chns[10].name][:]
time = td[gps[0].name][chns[10].name].time_track()

start=30
end=len(data)-10

tt = np.array(time[start:end])
dt = np.array(data[start:end])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, tt, dt)
resulting = func(time,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2])
plt.plot(time,data)
plt.plot(time,resulting)
plt.legend(['Actual Temp','Calculated Temp'])
```

I thought maybe the data type was incorrect, so I force it into a numpy array, but it did not change anything.

[Generate data set with portion of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvRdk.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the arrays dimensions have changed from `data` and `time` to `tt` and `dt`. Check they make sense with `tt.shape` etc. It's hard to tell since it's unclear what the type and shape of your original data (`data` and `time`).

Comment: I considered that, but unless I am missing something, that shouldn't be an issue, i checked the results and got :original data type - <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, shape - (3336,),  time type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, shape - (3336,), modified data type - <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, shape - (3296,), modified time type - <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, shape - (3296,).

Comment: Try `tt = time[start:end]` and same for `dt` - without passing them into `np.array()`.

Comment: I gave it a shot and received the same result.

Comment: I changed the amount of offset on the start and end, as long as I leave the combined offset less than 43 (i.e. start=23, end=len(data)-20), then it works alright. As soon as I go 1 datapoint less, it gives me the second result.

Comment: Very weird. Can you upload your data to somewhere and I'll try it myself? Hard to debug this way :)

Comment: I uploaded a reduced version of the data set and a copy of my current program here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FsI9aFL6_PMfIWwEHAe425Vk2EXZjHX7?usp=sharing